# Cant unzip file because of multiple files with same name in zip file in react-native

Tags: react-native, zip

I have been successfully unzipping zip files using react-native-zip-archive in react-native. But this time around the package fails to unzip the file because of existence of multiple files with same name in the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

A Zip file can indeed contain multiple files with the same name.
It's up to you to decide what to do in your program for this case when extracting them - and more generally, files that are already existing on the target system.